# I want to change colour of a <p> tag from red to green on clicking only one button

Tags: javascript, html

1st it will change the color to red clicking on a button and after that clicking on the same button `<p>` tag color will change to green. `function a()` and `c()` are not properly called.

```
<script>
function a() {
    document.getElementById("b").style.color="red";
    c();
}
function c() {
    document.getElementById("b").style.color="green";
}
</script>

<body>
    <p id="b">hello world!!</p>
    <button onclick="a();c()">ok</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
function toggleColor(){
    var elem = document.getElementById("b");
    elem.style.color = elem.style.color == "red"? "green" :"red";
}
</script>

<body>
    <p id="b">hello world!!</p>
    <button onclick="toggleColor();">ok</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The onClick callback is calling both methods on a single click. This means that the output will always be green as the c() function is the last called. Try using a swap approach instead with a single function.

```
<script>
function changeColor()
{
  var currentColor = document.getElementById("b").style.color;
  if(currentColor == "red"){
    document.getElementById("b").style.color = "green";
  }else {
    document.getElementById("b").style.color = "red";
  }
}
</script>

<body>
<p id="b">hello world!!</p>
<button onclick="changeColor()">ok</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using incorrect way to do that. You should check if the `p` has red coloring or green coloring and then change the color accordingly.

```
<script>
function a() {
if(document.getElementById("b").style.color == "green") {
    document.getElementById("b").style.color="red";
}
else { document.getElementById("b").style.color="green"; }
}
</script>

<body>
    <p id="b">hello world!!</p>
    <button onclick="a()">ok</button> <!-- call one function only -->
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/srsz65he/3/